# Convert Tree Structure to 2D Array

Tags: c#, arrays, tree

I need to convert a tree-type structure into a 2D array.

I have a person class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Children { get; } = new List<Person>();
}
```

Populated like this:

```
var parent = new Person {Name = "Parent"};
var child1 = new Person {Name = "Child 1"};
var grandchild1 = new Person {Name = "Grandchild 1"};
var child2 = new Person {Name = "Child 2"};

parent.Children.Add(child1);
child1.Children.Add(grandchild1);
parent.Children.Add(child2);
```

Eg:

```
| Parent |         |               |   
|        | Child 1 |               |
|        |         |  Grandchild 1 |
|        | Child 2 |               |
```

I want to convert it to the following array:

```
var expectedArray = new object[,]
{
    {"Parent", null, null},
    {null, "Child 1", null},
    {null, null, "Grandchild 1"},
    {null, "Child 2", null}
};
```

At the moment I've written a couple of extension methods but it's really messy. What's the correct way to do this? Preferably in a short contained method.

This is what I havae tried so far, but it's really messy.

```
public static class PersonExtensions
{
    public static object[,] To2DArray(this Person person)
    {
        var rowIndex = 0;
        var columnIndex = 0;

        var objectArray = new object[person.GetTotalPersonCount(), person.GetMaxDepth()];

        var stack = new Stack<List<Person>.Enumerator>();
        var enumerator = (new List<Person> {person}).GetEnumerator();
        enumerator.MoveNext();

        do
        {
            var currentPerson = enumerator.Current;
            objectArray[rowIndex, columnIndex] = currentPerson.Name;

            rowIndex++;
            if (currentPerson.Children.Any())
            {
                // Depth is increasing
                columnIndex++;
                stack.Push(enumerator);
                enumerator = currentPerson.Children.GetEnumerator();
            }

            // if (!enumerator.MoveNext() && stack.Count > 0)
            while (!enumerator.MoveNext() && stack.Count > 0)
            {
                // Depth is decreasing
                enumerator = stack.Pop();
                columnIndex--;
            }
        }
        while (stack.Count > 0);

        return objectArray;
    }

    public static int GetMaxDepth(this Person entity)
    {
        int maxDepth = 0;

        foreach (var childEntity in entity.Children)
        {
            maxDepth = Math.Max(maxDepth, childEntity.GetMaxDepth());
        }

        return maxDepth + 1;
    }

    public static int GetTotalPersonCount(this Person entity)
    {
        int count = 1;

        foreach (var childEntity in entity.Children)
        {
            count += childEntity.GetTotalPersonCount();
        }

        return count;
    }
}
```

**Edit**
I have managed to get it working by replacing the final if (depth descreasing) with a while. It still looks overly complicated though.

Comment: Is the maximum depth of the tree known? You've only shown 3, but can a grandchild have children? It looks like your solution is one the right track - what exact errors are you seeing?

Comment: No it's not known unfortuantely.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you feel you need the `tupleByEntity` dictionary - why can't you just directly fill each entry of the output `objectArray` as you go? At any rate I can't see any glaring errors in your logic.

Comment: If you assigned an ID number to all nodes, it would be real simple.. you could itterate out through each node wherever they are just adding myID, parentID, <stuff>

Comment: @Sefe Thanks have updated accordingly.

Comment: @DylanNicholson Yes you are right I don't need the Tuple, I had initially tried to separate the populating of the array from the traversing, but you are correct.

Comment: Looks like you found a way to fix your algorithm - now that you've done so, I can see that yes in principle you could do it with a single rather than a nested loop.  If you change it back to an 'if' but move to the top of the loop and ensure the other part of the loop only happens inside an "else", it should work as you expect - though you'll still have to handle the stack being empty as a termination case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how it should work as a single loop (untested!):

```
       for (; ; )
            if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                if (stack.Count == 0)
                    break; // finished
                           // Depth is decreasing
                enumerator = stack.Pop();
                columnIndex--;
            }
            else
            {
                var currentPerson = enumerator.Current;
                objectArray[rowIndex, columnIndex] = currentPerson.Name;

                rowIndex++;

                if (currentPerson.Children.Any())
                {
                    // Depth is increasing
                    columnIndex++;
                    stack.Push(enumerator);
                    enumerator = currentPerson.Children.GetEnumerator();
                }
            }
```

If you wanted it to look a little cleaner you could do something like:

```
 Func<bool> getNext = () => 
 { 
     if (!enumerator.MoveNext()) 
     { 
         if (stack.Count == 0) return false; 
         enumerator = stack.Pop(); columnIndex--; 
     } 
     return true; 
 };

 while (getNext())
 {
     var currentPerson = enumerator.Current;
     //etc.
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem can be solved by using depth-first search in two passes.
First, the height of the tree has to be determined in the first pass. The depth needs to be known in order to know how many entries will be in every line of the result.

Next, in a second pass, the actual entries have to be generated, assigning the node's name to the entry corresponding to its depth in the tree.

The first step can be done as follows by implementing it as an extension method of the `Person` class using Linq.

```
public static int Depth(this Person iPerson)
{
    if (iPerson.Children == null || iPerson.Children.Count() == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1 + Children.Max( iChild => iChild.Depth() );
    }
}
```

The second step can be implemented as follows, where `iRoot` is the root of the tree.

```
public static void DepthFirst(int Depth,
                              int CurrentDepth,
                              Person iRoot,
                              List<string>[] Result)
{
    string[] NewEntry = new string[Depth];
    NewEntry[CurrentDepth] = iPerson.Name;
    Result.Add(NewEntry);
    foreach(var iChild in iPerson.Children)
    {
        DepthFirst(Depth, CurrentDepth + 1, iChild, Result);
    }
}

int Depth = iRoot.Depth();
var Result = new List<string[]>();
DepthFirst(Depth, 0, iRoot, Result).
```

Comment: There two methods for doing this which I have detailed called GetMaxDepth and GetTotalPersonCount. I am currently using these.